# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Capacitor"

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cocoapods, capacitor

When i try "ionic cap sync"  there is a error in ios update

Error :

✖ Updating iOS native dependencies with "pod install" (may take several minutes):
✖ update ios:
[error] Error running update: Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Capacitor":
In Podfile:
Capacitor (from `../../node_modules/@capacitor/ios`)

Specs satisfying the `Capacitor (from` ../../node_modules/@capacitor/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

Podfile :

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
use_frameworks!

# workaround to avoid Xcode caching of Pods that requires
# Product -> Clean Build Folder after new Cordova plugins installed
# Requires CocoaPods 1.6 or newer
install! 'cocoapods', :disable_input_output_paths => true

def capacitor_pods
  # Automatic Capacitor Pod dependencies, do not delete
  pod 'Capacitor', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/ios'
  pod 'CapacitorCordova', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/ios'
  pod 'CapacitorCommunityAdmob', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor-community/admob'
  pod 'CapacitorCommunityFcm', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor-community/fcm'
  pod 'CordovaPlugins', :path => '../capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins'
  # Do not delete
end

target 'App' do
  capacitor_pods
  # Add your Pods here
end
```

ionic info :

Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.3.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.0.8
@angular/cli                  : 10.0.8
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

Capacitor:

Capacitor CLI   : 2.4.1
@capacitor/core : 2.4.1

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : not installed
Cordova Platforms : not available
Cordova Plugins   : not available

Utility:

cordova-res : not installed
native-run  : not installed

System:

NodeJS : v14.17.1 (/usr/local/bin/node)
npm    : 6.14.13
OS     : macOS Big Sur

------**SOLVED**------

I updated the capacitor and plugins to the latest version.it finally worked without error even though i had to make a few changes to the code(exmple imports so little changes)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One of the plugins you are using (or both) are updated for capacitor 3, which requires iOS 12, but you are still on capacitor 2, which allows iOS 11.

Ideally you should update to capacitor 3, but you can install older versions of the plugins, check their changelogs to see in which version they supported capacitor 3 and install the previous one.

Answer (score 34):

My issues comes after upgrade capacitor from 2.x to 3.x.  I fix it by changing:

File: ios/App/Podfile

Line:

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
```

to:

```
platform :ios, '12.0'
```

Comment: If anyone's found this after updating from Capacitor 3 to Capacitor 4 - it's the same; update from 12.0 to 13.0; and in XCode, change your build deployment target from 12.0 to 13.0 - details on that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63686967/xcode-unit-test-compiling-for-ios-12-but-module-has-minimum-deployment-targe

Comment: Actually - you shouldn't have to do this - `npx cap migrate` should handle this for you. More info here: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/updating/4-0

Comment: Just updating, the same error occurred with me now, and I updated from platform :ios, '12.0' to platform :ios, '13.0', and that occurred after upgrading capacitor 3 to 4.

Answer (score 10):

Update for capacitor 4, you can sort this out by running

```
npm i @capacitor/cli@latest
```

Then...

```
npx cap migrate
```